# Springfox: deny/prevent to use subclass as model from RestController body in swagger-ui

Tags: java, spring-boot, swagger-ui, swagger-2.0, springfox

i have 2 classes: `A` and `B` with `B extends A`.

```
@ApiModel("A")
public class A{}

@ApiModel("B")
public class B extends A{
    String foobar;
}
```

and i have 2 REST-Methods

```
@RestController
public class Controller{

    @PostMapping("A")
    public ResponseEntity<String> processA(
        @RequestBody @ApiParam(type = "A") final A input) {
        return "foo";
    }  

    @PostMapping("B")
    public ResponseEntity<String> processB(
        @RequestBody final B input) { 
        return "bar";
    }
}
```

springfox-ui show these both methods with the RequestBody `B`. The `@ApiParam(type = "A")` did not help.

I use springfox and springfox-ui version: 2.8, spring-boot version 1.5.10

How can i prevent/deny to use the subtype of a class as model and take the real type in `processA`?

Thx for your answers

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `@ApiImplicitParam` for this. This should work.

```
 @PostMapping("A")
  @ApiImplicitParam(dataType = "A",  name = "input")
  public String process(
      @RequestBody final A input) {
    return "foo";
  }
```

Comment: no it not work: I get the error with or without the @ApiModel definition and also with the full class-path as datatype:

Errors
Resolver error at paths./process.post.parameters.1.schema.$ref
Could not resolve reference because of: Could not resolve pointer: /definitions/A does not exist in document